# How to display or hide the errors in browser?

Tags: php

My question is about php. I want to know how to display or hide the errors in browser? I am just a begginer of php so i need a help in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use error_reporting, for more read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and this [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)